# Convert string to DateTime object with Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time, zoneddatetime

I want to covert the following string with a zoned offset to a type DateTime with the new Java 8 time library in the simplest way possible:

```
2016-04-11T22:56:00.000-0500
```

I've experimented with the ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME format and ZonedDateTime objects, but I just can't seem to find a simple way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The zone offset parser expects the offset to be in the format `-05:00` (with a `:`)

Comment: Java-8 does not have a type `DateTime`. Maybe you have confused this with Joda-Time. The Java-8-equivalent would be `ZonedDateTime` (or `OffsetDateTime` in this case).

Comment: @MenoHochschild My mistake, I meant a LocalDateTime object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a built-in formatter to parse that string, but it is fairly straightforward to create one:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSx");
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-04-11T22:56:00.000-0500", fmt);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem should look something like this:

```
String ts = "2016-04-11T22:56:00.000-0500";
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(ts, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

Comment: Getting the following exception (using Java 1.8_77 for context) and I assume the complaint is in regard to the hyphen character before the zoned offset:

Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-04-11T22:56:00.000-0500' could not be parsed at index 23
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
 at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
 at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: The provided formatter, ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME, is likely not defined to handle fractional seconds, which appear in your test string.  It also likely expects a colon between the hours and minutes in the offset.  You will therefore need to construct your own formatter to handle this case by using the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( )` function.